# Issues with scope

Tags: java, scope

I have no idea what is wrong with my code, it will not compile because the compiler can not find variable k.

my code:

```
public class t
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int r = 10;
        int c = 10;

        char[][] map = new char[r][c];

        for(int i = 1; i < (r - 1); i++)
        {
            for(int k = 1; k < (c - 1); k++);
            {
                map[i][k] = '$';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

error it's giving me:

```
  symbol:   variable k
  location: class t
  1 error
```

I keep thinking it is a scope issue, but `variable k` is inside of the nested for-loop, so it should be fine right?

Comment: In addition to dropping the semicolon: choose better names for your variables and class, and respect the Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a semicolon a the end of your "k" for loop; remove it.  Change

```
for(int k = 1; k < (c - 1); k++);
{
    map[i][k] = '$';
}
```

to

```
for(int k = 1; k < (c - 1); k++)
{
    map[i][k] = '$';
}
```

Comment: lol, thanks I was so focused on that k, I didn't see the semi-colon

Answer (score 3):

There is a small mistake in your code:

```
for(int k = 1; k < (c - 1); k++);
```

There shouldn't be semicolon at the end.

Answer (score 2):

semicolon at the end of your second loop, remove it and it will help your cause

```
for(int k = 1; k < (c - 1); k++);
                                ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because of additional semicolon at the end of below line...

```
for(int k = 1; k < (c - 1); k++)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int k = 1; k < (c - 1); k++);
```

Drop the `;`

---

## ***Elaboration:***

`;` is actually an empty statement which is valid in Java:

```
Foo f = new Foo();
;
f.doSomething();
```

In Java, you can have a control statement without curly braces `{` `}`, such as:

```
if(booleanFlag) doSomething();
else doSomethingElse();

// ...

for(String s : stringArray) System.out.println(s);
```

and that's what you have used in your code:

```
for(int k = 1; k < (c - 1); k++); // iterate on the empty statement
```

Then, you opened a new block of code that has nothing to do with the for-loop:

```
{
    map[i][k] = '$';
}
```

which is executed only once.

Answer (score 1):

You have an semicolon at the end of the `for loop` that initializes `k` -- remove that and you should be fine!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semicolon after the second `for` loop.

Semicolon is a legitimate statement called null statement; that means "do nothing".